# Sending mms in android 4.4

Tags: android, telephony, mms

I'm trying to send mms from my app only. I made it default messaging app with help of android developers tutorial (http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html).

My manifest:

BroadcastReceiver that listens for incoming SMS messages:

```
   <receiver android:name="com.test.SmsReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

BroadcastReceiver that listens for incoming MMS messages

```
 <receiver android:name="com.test.MmsReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_DELIVER" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Service that delivers messages from the phone quick response

```
<service android:name="com.test.HeadlessSmsSendService"
        android:permission="android.permission.SEND_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="sms" />
            <data android:scheme="smsto" />
            <data android:scheme="mms" />
            <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

**NewMmsActivity** Activity that allows the user to send new SMS/MMS messages:

```
 <activity android:name="com.test.NewMmsActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="sms" />
            <data android:scheme="smsto" />
            <data android:scheme="mms" />
            <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

But when I try in **NewMmsActivity** to send an mms it doesn't work and instead dialog is open like this:

[image]

CODE:

```
  Intent mmsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  mmsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "text");
  mmsIntent.putExtra("address", "99999999");
  mmsIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(fileString)));
  mmsIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
  startActivity(mmsIntent);
```

If I use Intent.ACTION_SENDTO nothing happens. Intent is started without no problems but nothing is happening.

What am I missing?

Comment: Could you expand on "doesn't work". Do you get errors? Image doesn't show up?

Comment: @RyPope: nothing happens. Intent starts but nothing gets sent.

Comment: Okay, give my answer a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way i found for sending mms is android-smsmms library found here: https://github.com/klinker41/android-smsmms

For gettings mmsc, proxy and port i used:

```
 final Cursor apnCursor = SqliteWrapper.query(mContext, this.mContext.getContentResolver(),
                Uri.withAppendedPath(Telephony.Carriers.CONTENT_URI, "current"), APN_PROJECTION, null, null, null);
        String type = null;
        if (apnCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                type = apnCursor.getString(3);
                if(type.equals("default,supl,mms") ||
                        type.equals("mms")) {
                    mmsc = apnCursor.getString(0);
                    proxy = apnCursor.getString(1);
                    port = apnCursor.getString(2);
}while (apnCursor.moveToNext());
```

In if loop i am checking if APN has MMS data that i need otherwise go to next one.

Comment: How do you get Mmsc, Port and Proxy from android?

Comment: how do You get acces to hiden class `SqlliteWrapper`? i try do it by `ContentResolver` but only i get is _Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: No permission to write APN settings: Neither user 10656 nor current process has android.permission.WRITE_APN_SETTINGS._

Comment: You can find these files in smsmms library which i posted above (or get them from Android source code yourself). So when you make SqlliteWrapper object make sure it is smsmms library one.

Comment: after i change it to sqliteWrapper from android soucre from git i still get that exception, this perrmision is system permission so i cant get it

Comment: Maybe try setting your app as default messaging app?

Comment: sorry for not respond, got many to do, app set to sms default still eception, on lib git site thet add sample i will try run it

Comment: sample from they git can get some apn data but it cannot send it anyway ty i will go to git now

Comment: For sending mms the library i provided in link didn't work instantly for me also. I had to delete few lines in library to make it work.

Comment: i finally found problem and solution with help from library developer https://github.com/klinker41/android-smsmms/issues/23

Answer (score 1):

As the default app, yours is responsible for sending the MMS itself, not opening another app to do so, which is what your code is doing. Currently, Android does not have a simple API for MMS, as it does for SMS. Furthermore, it is a very poorly documented aspect of the framework, and the amount of code and explanation necessary to implement it is out of scope for Stack Overflow. You're welcome to inspect the source code of the native app for guidance, but keep in mind that it is no trivial task, as the default app is responsible for everything needed to handle MMS, including sending, receiving, and Content Provider transactions.

Comment: But why would there be schemes like "mmsto:", etc. If it's not possible?

Comment: I didn't say it's not possible, just that it's not trivial, and your app would have to handle it, which is why your `NewMmsActivity` includes that scheme in its `<intent-filter>`.

Comment: That blog page (which nearly everyone references in trying to update SMS apps for KitKat) is rather misleading, in that it neglects to mention that MMS operations have never been easily implemented in Android, even though any app meant to be a default must handle them.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that you are trying to send both image and text data, but your type is set to image.
Try switching this instead to:

```
mmsIntent.setType("*/*");
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I tried changing from ACTION_SEND to ACTION_SENDTO also, because ACTION_SEND opens choose dialog and nothing happens.

Comment: As in nothing appears in the dialog?