# how to send voice message to another contact number without opening in built message app?

Tags: android, message, voice

i want to send voice message to another number. i tried

```
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    sendIntent.setClassName("com.android.mms", "com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity");
    sendIntent.putExtra("address", "5556");
    sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "if you are sending text");   
    final File file1 = new File(outputFile);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file1);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    sendIntent.setType("Audio/mp3");
    startActivity(sendIntent);
```

but it goes to default voice message.but i need to  voice message  send through  my app.

Comment: Android currently has no simple MMS API, as it does for SMS. You're welcome to inspect the AOSP source for Messenger to glean how it's accomplished (it is not trivial), but the easiest way would probably be to use a 3rd-party library.

Comment: pls suggest one library.

Comment: I personally have not used any, nor do I know of any, but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26058986/2850651) mentions and links to one. I cannot vouch for it.