# How do I text an image (MMS) in one of my project's folders?

Tags: java, android, mms

Say I have an image at `app/images/image.png`.

How do I text that image to another phone?

In other words, how do I send an MMS?

I've written some SMS-sending code, but it doesn't work when I replace "Sms" with "Mms":

```
        try {
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            ArrayList<String> parts = smsManager.divideMessage(msg);
            smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNo, null, parts, null, null);
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    "SMS sent",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show();
            Log.v("sendSMSMessage",msg);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    "Failed to send. Try again.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: As of yet, there is no simple MMS API in Android, like that for SMS. There are third-party solutions available, however, and I've seen at least one open source library mentioned in [an answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26058986/2850651). Of course, you could always check out the source code for the AOSP Messenger app and roll your own, but it is not trivial.