# I can not send MMS in android

Tags: android, sms, sendmessage, mms, multimedia

I am developing the application, but I can not send MMS messages. I studied sample code. Does not solve my problem wants me to choose another application. I want to send MMS from my own application, but I can not. I would appreciate if you can help

```
 Intent smsIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", mContext.getString(R.string.app_name)); 
        smsIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse("file://" + imagePath));
        smsIntent.setType("image/png");
        mContext.startActivity(smsIntent);
```

I do not call this code. It wants me to choose another application.

Comment: As of yet, there is no simple MMS API in Android, like that for SMS. There are third-party solutions available, however, and I've seen at least one open source library mentioned in [an answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26058986/2850651). Of course, you could always check out the source code for the AOSP Messenger app and roll your own, but it is not trivial.

Answer (score 0):

The MMS functionality of android is placed within the SMS/MMS application; the platform only provides fundamental support for wap push notifications, and obviously basic socket functionality etc.

If you want to write your own app that sends MMS you have to implement the entire OMA MMS specification within your app. By simply using intents you can at most launch the SMS/MMS app with pre-filled phonenumber, text, images etc, but not send any message silently without user interaction.

Since Android is open source you can however of course be inspired by parts of the AOSP SMS/MMS app source code. Mind you, this is not a trivial task.

Comment: Do you have a recommendation for example, or source

Comment: Well, not other than guiding you to the location of the AOSP Mms application: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Mms

This is a pretty complicated state machine. Of course, if you only need to send MMS, not receive, you only need some parts of the MMS protocol stack, namely support for encoding and sending m-send-req primitives. 

I am sure you can google for more info from this, I would guess you're not the first to do this. This is not the type of question that is answered with a one-liner that solves the problem for you, this requires extensive research and effort.

Comment: very complicated. I have difficulty understanding. I completed the SMS function. I completed listelemeleri SMS and MMS. I could not figure to send MMS. I looked at before you give project. I do not know anything much